# foreach does not process an array for insert into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I would like to ask why the foreach does not insert record of all the data from $listname array but instead it only insert the last item from the array but if I do echo $fname inside foreach I could see the records. thanks

```
 $last_id = $db_->lastInsertId();

   foreach ($listname as $fname) {
           $new_name->bindParam(':fname',fname);
           $new_name->bindParam(':id',$last_id);
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either some of your code is missing or you're just overwriting the parameters as you iterate through the for loop. You need to prepare the statement and, in your loop:

1. bind the parameters
2. then execute

For each set of values you want to insert.

```
   $last_id = $db_->lastInsertId();

   $name = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO name SET fname=:fname, id=:id");

   foreach ($listname as $fname) {
       $name->bindParam(':fname',fname);
       $name->bindParam(':id',$last_id);
       $name->execute();
   }
```

Comment: I do have prepare statement for insert 
$name = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO name SET fname=:fname, id=:id");

and my $name->execute(); and the bind parameters is under the foreach. could you please provide a sample code? thanks

Comment: I added some sample code. Note how the execute is inside the loop so it executes for each set of parameters.